# How can I compare two stored texts, if they are partially equal (in selenium IDE)

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have two strings say

a = "Your transaction is successful, The ref number is 12345"

and

b = "Your Transaction is successful"

I need to compare these two strings. How can i do this in Selenium IDE.

Comment: What do you mean by compare? To see if they're equal or what or just see if string A contains string b?

Answer (score 0):

You should get this text use ' IWebElement.Text' and assigned to varible. Next You can simply compare for example use nunit : AssertIsTrue(text1 == text2).

Comment: and if You want equal only part of text you can cut part. Example in c# you can use: a.Remove(27). @7 - It is mean that 27 i start to remove.

Comment: or method Contains :) a.Contains(b)

Comment: Thanks for ur efforts my friend but I need this in IDE, I know how to manipulate it using Java, but I need it in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If both strings always start with "your transaction is successful", then do a storeEval to substring to only get that part of both strings(or at least for string B, so the length is the same).

When I compare strings using the IDE, I always downcase both strings so I don't have to worry about case issues when comparing them.

storeEval | var s=storedVars['A']; s.toLowerCase(); | A1

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you simply want to test to see if string B is in string A.
ofcourse replace a with storedVars[a] if you've used variable.

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyEval</td>
    <td>a='abctestabc'; b='test'; a.indexOf(b) &gt; -1;</td>
    <td>true</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys I really appreciate all your answers but,
I found a way using which I can actually compare these strings and get the output, the thing which I have implemented is as follows :

```
VerifyText  ||      css="TheLocationFromWhichTheTextIsBeingFetched" || Your Transaction is successful*
```

so basically I used the golbe. :)
But Thanks a lot to all your replies, I could deduct this from your solutions only. Thank You!